# Multiple instances of Postfix throwing error fatal: unknown service: smtp/tcp

Tags: freebsd, postfix

I am trying to configure multiple postfix-2.12 instances on FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE following the [README](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html).

```
postmulti -e init
postmulti -I postfix-out -G mta -e create
...
```

This all works I can start and stop instances everything seems good. When I test sending an email locally using telnet. Postfix logs the following `fatal: unknown service: smtp/tcp` error.

The configuration files are vanilla no chroot in master.cf.

```
 mynetworks = 127.0.0.1/8 192.168.5.0/24
```

If I run postfix as a single instance everything works fine. So postfix can read `/etc/services` when run as a single instance.

The spool directory that is created with postmulti looks identical to postfix spool dir.

I have been hammering at this for way too long. Has anyone implemented multiple instances of  postfix on FreeBSD or can give some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

For the best quality answers, you will need to post the content of master.cf and more details about your configuration.    But, looking at my configuration for example:

```
==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

Here we see that the smtp listener runs in a chroot environment.    There should be a usable copy of /etc/services in that chroot directory:

```
$ grep '^smtp' $(sudo postconf -h queue_directory)/etc/services
smtp        25/tcp      mail
```

If there is an etc/services file under the queue directory but it has the wrong content, or the file is not there, re-check the postfix installation instructions to make sure they were carried out correctly.

Comment: I had a similar issue and fixed it by copying both `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/services` into the chrooted postfix queue directory.

Comment: @Phssthpok same for me! I'd like to know why http://serverfault.com/questions/661621/why-do-i-have-to-manually-copy-etc-services-and-etc-resolv-conf-into-var-spoo

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I made a second instance of postfix and my second-instance-master.cf is

```
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
ip.second.eth.card:smtp  inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

Comment: Do you still have the same problem although you made a second instance? Or **did** you have the same problem and did the extra line solve this?